# Как сериализовать несколько экземпляров класса?

Tags: xml, java

Хочу сериализовать несколько экземпляров класса в XML файл с помощью JAXB. Один класс легко сериализовать, а вот несколько - уже проблема. Покажите, как это можно сделать.

Пользовался кодом, который вот тут нашел: [JAXB-Demo](https://github.com/Maduranga/JAXB-Demo/blob/master/src/Person.java).

Вот примерно так вывожу лист:

```
ArrayList<Campaign> cam = new ArrayList<Campaign>();
    cam.add(camp); // добавляем объект класс Campaign 
    cam.add(camp2); // добавляем объект класс Campaign

    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Campaign.class);
    Marshaller marsh = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    marsh.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    marsh.marshal(cam,new FileOutputStream("ololo.xml"));
```

Comment: Ну сериализуйте коллекцию нужных вам элементов

Comment: Вам что каждый шаг подсказывать? столько однообразных вопросов про сериализацию. Или хотя бы обновляли бы старый вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

JAXB поддерживает сериализацию списков. Поэтому достаточно создать список с объектами, подлежащими сериализации, и сериализовать его.

Другой подход - это вместо JAXB использовать [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/). Он сериализует сложные иерархии объектов.

Comment: Что-то не получается, можете на коде показать, как это будет выглядеть?

Comment: Где можно почитать про сериализацию списков в JAXB?